# How do I highlight the current page and parent?

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm having a tough time understanding how to highlight a menu item on my current project. I've spent hours looking for solutions and always end up stumped. My jquery isn't that good. Here's the menu I have. How can I get it so the current page is highlighted, but also the parent of the child is highlighted as well for the dropdown menus. Some codes would also highlight multiple pages at once. Can someone explain why?

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
<a href="index.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a>           
</li>

    <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Marketing Tours<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="tour_management.php">Tour Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="tour_management.php#leasing">Leasing</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php#case_studies">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>

    </li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Specialty Vehicles <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="experiential_build.php">Experiential Builds</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile_cinema.php">Mobile Cinema (CineTransformer)</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile_broadcast.php">Mobile Broadcast/Production</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile_stage.php">Mobile Stage</a></li>
    <li><a href="military&government.php">Military/Government</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Trailers</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

    <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Creative<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="about.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"> About </a>         
    </li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="contact.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Contact </a>            

        </li>                           
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm having problems understanding when and what exactly you want highlight

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For example if im on the page experiential_build.php i would like "Specialty Vehicles" and "Experiential Builds" to have a li class of active or current.

Comment: I think you can play with the `click`event. On each click highlight the `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly easy, depending on how this is set up. jQuery is probably not necessary. Instead, whatever script you have building out the menu should be set up so that it adds an active trail to the LI classes, which can then be styled with CSS. Without seeing the system that builds the menu, it would be difficult to provide a more detailed response.

Comment: Well, then your job is quite a bit more difficult. If you want to do it in jQuery, you need to read the file name from the URL, find that specific link within your menu, then add a class to the link's parent LI.